# Can I Combine Two Three-Way Switches and Add Outlet?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, receptacle

I have two three-way switches that I would like to combine into a two combination three-way switch and add an outlet. Is there anything wrong with doing this? I am thinking of wiring them both to the combination switch and then tapping off of that to add an outlet. Please let me know if more info is needed.

[image: Current Configuration]

[image]

Comment: Can you post photos looking into the backs of the boxes please?

Comment: How would you feel about replacing these boxes with a 3-gang box, and converting at least one of the 3-ways to a smart switch?

Comment: _(corrected to link to the tour)_ Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Please take our [tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to combine those to 3-way switches with the switch you have shown. You'll need a double 3-way combination switch, which is two 3-way switches combined. It looks very similar to the one you have shown but with two extra screws.

With the wires shown in your picture, adding the outlet won't work. You've either got load wires or hot wires or a combination of both connecting to the common terminal of the 3-way switches and I don't see a neutral in there. You might be able to fish a hot, neutral and ground to that location for the outlet. Hope this helps.